# Put() sometimes throws exception when trying to assign drive letter to partition

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I have a simple script that assigns a drive letter to any unlettered partition, like the following:

```
function GetNextAvailableLetter
{
  #returns an unused char for drive letter assignment, or $null if none are available
}

foreach ($disk in ( get-wmiobject -class win32_volume | where-object { $_.DriveLetter -eq $null } ) )
{
  $letter = GetNextAvailableLetter
  if ( $letter -ne $null )
  {
    $disk.DriveLetter = $letter + ":"
    $disk.Put()
  }
}
```

Oddly, sometimes it'll work, and sometimes `Put()` throws an exception:

```
Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Not supported"
```

I have no idea why `Put()` would throw.

Comment: My first guess would be that `$disk` might contain more that one object. When that occurs what does the output of `$disk` or `$disk.Count`. Wonder if you have more than one element there

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately, that didnt seem to be the problem. I've updated my question using a foreach loop to clarify. With these changes, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Too bad but at least we are farther. Maybe that will help someone else. Saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230277/powershell-and-diskpart as well if it helps. Uses some other commands to mount. Also calls put as `.Put_`. What is the disk type of $disk.

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of empty, driveletterless drives on my computer and was able to recreate this and one other error that I think you *might* have neglected to mention.

```
Property 'DriveLetter' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:2 char:1
+ $disk.DriveLetter = "Q:"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied.
"
At line:3 char:1
+ $disk.Put()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The way to solve this would be run the variable `$disk` though for each loop or something along those lines. Another approach would be to check the `$disk.Count` ahead of time.

```
$disk = get-wmiobject -class win32_volume | where-object { $_.DriveLetter -eq $null }
If (($disk) -and ($disk.Count -eq 1)){
    $disk.DriveLetter = "Q:"
    $disk.Put()
}
```

The `If` should in theory protect you from errors when `$disk` is empty or returns more that one object.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Scripting Guys](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/14/change-drive-letters-and-labels-via-a-simple-powershell-command.aspx):

> The reason for this error is that the Windows PowerShell prompt is not running with Administrator rights. Unfortunately, the error that bubbles back up from WMI does not tell us that the problem is related to rights.